# Characterizing the D4 lattice as a sphere packing

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, lattices

Suppose I pack spheres in $\mathbb{R}^4$ in such a way that each touches 24 others.  (All spheres in my question are assumed to have equal radius and be non-overlapping.)   Does this packing necessarily give the [$\mathrm{D}_4$ lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-cell_honeycomb#D4_lattice) up to translation, rotation and rescaling?  Or more precisely: has this been proved?

I think I know the status of a few related conjectures:

1. In 2003 [Oleg Musin proved that the kissing number in 4 dimensions is 24](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309430): i.e., the maximum number of equal-sized nonoverlapping spheres that can touch another equal-sized sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is 24.
2. It's conjectured that the only way to achieve the kissing number of 24 in 4 dimensions is to have the spheres centered at the vertices (and center) of a regular [24-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell).  This conjecture was still open [as of 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04099).
3. It's conjectured that the $\mathrm{D}_4$ lattice gives the densest packing of spheres in $\mathbb{R}^4$. This conjecture was open [as of 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04099), and it will probably be big news if it's ever proved.
4. In 1872 [Korkin and Zolatarev proved that the $\mathrm{D}_4$ lattice gives the densest *lattice* packing of spheres in $\mathbb{R}^4$](https://eudml.org/doc/156587).
5. In 2017 [Oleg Musin reported some progress on the 24-cell conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04099), which says that the minimal volume of any cell in the Voronoi decomposition of a packing of $\mathbb{R}^4$ by unit spheres is at least as large as the volume of a regular 24–cell circumscribed around a unit sphere.  Musin says this conjecture would imply conjecture 3.

Would settling any of these settle my question?  Would settling my question settle any of these?   (I can imagine a positive answer to question 2 would imply a positive answer to my question, but I think it would take at least a bit of work.)